Matplotlib: Customize the frequency of Y Axis ticks to be every 2 or 5
I have this output of plot.

What I want to do is to set the horizontal line's tick to 0.
(More important) to set the frequency of values shown on right and left (Y axis) to be tidier. I managed to have on right to have every from -50 to 30 with the next code.

Code:
def round_down(value, base=5):
    return base * np.floor(value / base)

def round_up(value, base=5):
    return base * np.ceil(value / base)

# aligning ticks
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax2.set_ylim(bottom=round_down(min(plot_data.VAR3), 10) ,top=round_up(max(plot_data.VAR3), 10))

But I don't know for instance how to make it happen every 2 or 5 frequency for the left Y Axis.

Here is the whole code
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# Create a twin Axes sharing the xaxis
ax2 = ax1.twinx() # Making a twin of a first axis

lns1 = [ax1.bar(plot_data.date, plot_data.VAR2,  color= 'yellow', label="VAR2 Ratio", width= 50)] #Plotting a barplot on left axis
lns2= ax2.plot(plot_data.date, plot_data.VAR1, 'blue', label = "VAR1  (RHS)") #Plotting a line on rigth axis
lns3 = ax2.plot(plot_data.date, plot_data.VAR3, 'red',label= "VAR3 (RHS)") #Plotting again a line on right axis


lns = lns1+lns2+lns3 # Getting all together
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns] # Getting the names of lables
ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.2), #Location of label
          fancybox=False, shadow=False, ncol=5,frameon= False) #Frameon if you want to eliminate the frames
# ax1.set_xticklabels(labs, fontsize=6) #font size for the X values

def round_down(value, base=5):
    return base * np.floor(value / base)

def round_up(value, base=5):
    return base * np.ceil(value / base)

# aligning ticks
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax2.set_ylim(bottom=round_down(min(plot_data.VAR3), 10) , top= round_up(max(plot_data.VAR3), 10))

ax2.axhline(y=0, color='black', linewidth=1, linestyle='--')



# 5 ticks from each side to have aligned 
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LinearLocator(5))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LinearLocator(5))

# To add a percentage to tick
formatter = ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=100, decimals=0)

# Set setting Y axis ticks
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

# setting the frames of a viz
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

# FontSize of tick
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8, rotation=45) # Rotating ticks horizontally

start_date = plot_data.date.min()
ax1.set_xlim([start_date-1, plot_data.date.max()])
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %y')) #Setting the format of ticks to MM YY
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3)) #Setting the frequency of ticks

ax1.grid(axis='y',  color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.25, zorder=0)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

plt.show()



I did a small example for you where I have x, y1, and y2:
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 10)
y1 = 50*np.exp(-x/10) + 5
y2 = 10*np.exp(x/100)

I did the following function that takes the variable and generates ticks and labels for it:
def getTicksAndLabels(y, spacing = 5):
    minVal = np.floor(min(y) / spacing) * spacing # get suitable limit in min
    maxVal = np.ceil(max(y) / spacing) * spacing # get suitable limit in max
    ticks = np.arange(minVal, maxVal + 1, spacing) # define the ticks you want to set
    # maybe loop is not the best idea? don't know
    labels = [str(int(tick)) for tick in ticks] # generate labels as string
    return ticks, labels

And so the plotting will look something like this:
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y1, "-o")
plt.yticks(*getTicksAndLabels(y1, 2))
plt.ylabel("y1 = 50*np.exp(-x/10) + 5")
plt.twinx()
plt.plot(x,y2, "r-s")
plt.yticks(*getTicksAndLabels(y2, 5))
plt.grid()
plt.ylabel("y2 = 10*np.exp(x/100)")
plt.xlabel("x")

The results:

The left side is spaced every 2, and the right every 5. The ticks are automatically generated if you pass the right stuff to the function. Hope this helps.
Imports:
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Hey! You are great in python really appreciate it. It works for me but only thing that I want left and right hand to be aligned. For instance on right I have 5 ticks that should correspond to the position of ticks on left. I have realized this later. How should I
ax1.yticks(*getTicksAndLabels(plot_data.VAR1, 5))
ax2.yticks(*getTicksAndLabels(plot_data.VAR2, 5))

I changed a code like this but didn't get desired result

One more thing. I want couldn't set the upper limit to be the max + rounded to the next 5 or 10 of a value

@Amirgiano i'll take a look tomorrow, maybe open another question?

@Amirgiano this makes the problem quite complicated to automatically solve. We would have to find common ticks between spacing every 5 and every 2, which only overlaps half of the times since 1 in 2 ticks of spacing 5 is odd... am not sure I can supply you with a better solution

@Amirgiano regardubg setting the upper to max+spacing, just use     maxVal = np.ceil(max(y) / spacing) * spacing + spacing in the function
